# When debugging in IntelliJ how can I tell in which inner class am I placed in?

Tags: debugging, navigation, intellij-idea

I am debugging some 3rd party code in IntelliJ 11 and came across following problem.

The code is structured slightly strange so every `.java` source file contains lot of inner classes, those inner classes also contain inner classes etc. Now if I step on a line of code with a debugger, is there a way to tell immediatelly which class (inner class maybe?) I am in?

In the breadcrubms line on the top I see alway only a path to the current `.java` source file. Maybe there is a setting which allow to display inner classes in the breadcrumbs bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (`View` | `Context Info`) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (`Navigate` | `File Structure`).

Comment: Multiple ALT+Q do the trick but still would be nicer if the information is available without the need of pressing anything ... Thanks anyway. +1

Comment: If you are IntelliJ developer could you comment on the idea having inner classes in the navigation bar?

Comment: We already have a feature request for this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-37112, please vote.